# Retrieve all the selected Id's values from a drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an entity called `InvestigatorGroupData` with the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class InvestigatorGroupData
{

        [DataMember]
        public int InvestigatorGroupId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string InvestigatorGroupName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool HasGameAssignment { get; set; }

}
```

I've created the following view model:

```
public class InvestigatorGroupModel
{
    public IEnumerable<InvestigatorGroupData> groupList {get;set;}
    public int SelectedInvestigatorGroupId { get; set; }

}
```

And pass it to the view as follows:

```
InvestigatorGroupModel groupModel = new InvestigatorGroupModel();

GameClient proxy = new GameClient();
groupModel.groupList = proxy.GetInvestigatorGroups(User.Identity.GetUserId());
proxy.Close();

return View("SelectGroup", groupModel);
```

The dropdownlist for my view looks like this:
`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedInvestigatorGroupId,new SelectList(Model.groupList, "InvestigatorGroupId", "InvestigatorGroupName"))`

I would like a user to be able to select an `InvestigatorGroupName`, and for the associated `InvestigatorGroupData` to be returned (not just the Selected Id). As of now, only the `SelectedInvestigatorGroupId` is returned/posted and the groupList is null

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example:

```
InvestigatorGroupModel groupModel = new InvestigatorGroupModel();

GameClient proxy = new GameClient();
groupModel.groupList = proxy.GetInvestigatorGroups(User.Identity.GetUserId());
proxy.Close();

//Save the list of InvestigatorGroupData objects to be retrieved later
HttpContext.Current.Session["GroupList"] = groupModel.groupList;

return View("SelectGroup", groupModel);
```

And then in your post controller action:

```
//Grab the list of InvestigatorGroupData objects that was saved before
IEnumerable<InvestigatorGroupData> groupList = (IEnumerable<InvestigatorGroupData>)HttpContext.Current.Session["GroupList"];

int investigatorGroupId = groupModel.SelectedInvestigatorGroupId;

InvestigatorGroupData selectedGroup = groupList.Single(l => l.investigatorGroupId == investigatorGroupId);
```

`selectedGroup` will be the `InvestigatorGroupData` object which corresponds with the chosen entry from the drop-down list.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, that's not possible using a `DropDownListFor`... Parameter 1 of a `DropDownListFor` is the field in your model which the value attribute of the select list binds to.

If you want to get a reference to the entire object entity on post, then you will need to go perform a DB lookup based upon the ID that is returned from your view.

Comment: The way the application will work is that if a user has multiple groups they will be prompted to select a group. Then, if a user has multiple games they will be prompted select a game, etc.. I am already pulling the groups from the db/service to see if there is more than 1 group and what the names and id's are. So what you are saying is that I will have to pull from the db again on the post to lookup the entity again and do two pulls from the db for the select a game as well? Is there a way to reduce the times I hit the DB/Service?

Comment: Yes, with a `DropDownListFor` you can only post back 1 field (in your case an ID), not an entire object reference. Without knowing how your code works I can't answer your reduce DB/Service question.

Comment: Technically, I guess you *could* post back the entire object. Convert your object to JSON and store that in the value attribute of the `DropDownListFor` and then on the post back build a mapper to make a new object from that JSON. But there is no easy native way to accomplish what you're after

Comment: There are tricks you can do with hidden fields to cause the data which populates lists to be posted back with the model, however these are hackish and very difficult to implement for any kind of complex data.  A better way to do this would be to store your objects in session on page load, and then retrieve them on the post, or you can accomplish the same thing using TempData, however that will only persist its value through the very first subsequent request after it's set (not guaranteed to be the post you're looking for).

Comment: If I were to use TempData would I have to store the entire list of entities in there or would there be a way to store only the selected entity from the drop down list?

Comment: @EitanK You would have to store the entire list. HTTP Web Programming is stateless, so the Web server has absolutely no idea that select list has changed until a post back (poor term) occurs either as a full  POST of Ajax request occurs. At that point, only the parameters that are included are available to be read. Your session data is persistent across page loads, but session data should only be used to store small bits of information (eg.. a User ID), not entire entity objects.

Comment: You won't know what the selected entry is until they post the form back, so you'd need to save the entire list.  I would recommend using session instead though, because as I indicated previously, TempData can sometimes behave in unexpected ways.  You have better control over Session.  See the answer I added for an example of how to do this.

Comment: @Redit0 I am just worried about using session because cant the session values be manipulated (i.e: the id's be changed) which would cause possible access of data that shouldn't be accessed?

Comment: Data stored in the session is physically located in memory on the web server itself, not in the client's cookies or other local store.  It is possible to manipulate the session id, however that would break the association between the browsing user and 'their' session.  Unless the session ID was manipulated in such a way that the new ID matches another valid session (unlikely), the only thing that is likely to happen is that they would see the site as if they had no session at all.  If authentication is implemented properly, including AntiForgeryToken, you're pretty safe from this.